# COINCHANGE: dynamic programing O(N) complexity

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following problem:

You are given a set of coins S. In how many ways can you make sum N assuming you have infinite amount of each coin in the set.

Note : Coins in set S will be unique. Expected space complexity of this problem is O(N).
Note that the answer can overflow. So, give us the answer % 1000007

I have the following solution using DP

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> memo = new HashMap<>();
public int coinchange2(List<Integer> a, int b) {
    return use(a, 0, b);
}

private int use(List<Integer> a, Integer index, int n) {
    if(memo.containsKey(a.get(index))) {
        if(memo.get(a.get(index)).containsKey(n)) {
            return memo.get(a.get(index)).get(n);
        }
    }
    if(n == 0 && a.get(index)>=0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if((n > 0 && a.get(index) == 0) || n < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int nbWays = 0;
    for(int i = index; i < a.size(); i++) {
        nbWays += use(a, i, n - a.get(i))%1000007;
    }

    if(!memo.containsKey(a.get(index))) {
        memo.put(a.get(index), new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());  
    }
    nbWays = nbWays % 1000007;
    memo.get(a.get(index)).put(n, nbWays);
    return nbWays;
}
```

But I still do not met the requirements:
"Partially Correct Answer. Make your solution more efficient"

Do you know what could cause this code to not be O(N) complexity?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it could be that you're recursively calling use() in a for loop which has O(n). In the first run, you call use() a.size() times, once for each index in a, so this is at least O(n^2), right?

Can you debug it line by line to maybe see how many times you call use()? Or even for now just increment a counter each time use() is called so you have an idea of how many runs you're going through.

All your other methods within here are O(1) (I think), so I feel like it's gotta be that loop.

Comment: I think you are right the counter on use indicate O(n^2) complexity, thank you!

Comment: You put me on the good tracks, I will rework this version and add a response with a Java version with O(N) complexity when I get to it!

Answer (score 1):

The Change-making problem can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).  The code here is in Python. [Geeks for Geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/) has the solution in C/C++ , which is a lot closer to Java syntactically. Please take the time to read one or the other completely to understand the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ can [lead to your answer being deleting](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).